# Рефлексия event'ов (как получить методы , подписаны на event)

Tags: c#, события, рефлексия

Суть задачи в том, чтобы контролировать подписки на event. Если этот какой то метод уже подписан , то удалить повторяющуюся ссылку на него . Реализовать необходимо сторонним методом (с add и remove самого event все легко получилось). EventInfo я получаю, но извлечь из него конкретные методы не получается . В сам метод передаю экземпляр , в котором и содержится этот event

Comment: А класс где определён event вы можете менять или это чужой класс?

Comment: Если нет прямого доступа к делегату то честным путем получить список подписчиков не получится - event как и свойство, сам по себе данных не содержит, делегат нужен.

Comment: я должен иметь возможность просмотреть event любого класса. 
То есть мне надо получить делегат, создать экземпляр этого делегата, и каким то образ соотнести этот делегат и event?

Comment: Универсального способа не существует, все зависит от конкретной реализации. Под обычным `event` в классе может скрываться поле в виде мультикаст делегата, или какой-нибудь `EventHandlerList`, или вообще routed event из WPF. Вам придется искать свой подход для каждого класса.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51289/discussion-on-question-by-mikhail-znak--event---).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FieldInfo[] infoEvent = getType.GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.GetField); 

foreach (FieldInfo item in infoEvent)
{ 
    Delegate myDelegate = (Delegate)item.GetValue(obj);
    Delegate [] mas = myDelegate.GetInvocationList();
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3783267/how-to-get-a-delegate-object-from-an-eventinfo

Comment: Это сработает только в случае, если список подписчиков события лежит в приватном поле. Для классов с большим количеством событий (вроде стандартного Control), которые [хранят подписчиков на события в EventHandlerList](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,eb6b0a8a2eb29f3c,references) это не сработает. Ну и к тому же тут нет никакой гарантии что вы получаете именно делегаты списка подписчиков, а не просто какой-то делегат в приватном поле. Т.е. с таким подходом можно вычистить все подряд, а не только нужное событие.